# How to use a BooleanQuery builder in Lucene 5.3.x?

Tags: java, lucene, information-retrieval

I'm almost new to lucene and trying to AND some queries and display them.
I've googled for entire web, though could't find the correct solution to this problem. The solutions for boolean query search include `BooleanQuery` Lucene class, but this class is [deprecated in Lucene 5.3.1](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html) (the one that I'm using)

This is a part of my code:

```
public static void searchBooleanQuery(String indexDir, Query query1,
                                       Query query2, Query query3, Query query4) throws IOException {
    IndexReader rdr =  DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(indexDir)));
    IndexSearcher is = new IndexSearcher(rdr);
    BooleanQuery.Builder booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
    booleanQuery.add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    booleanQuery.add(query2, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    booleanQuery.add(query3, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    booleanQuery.add(query4, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
}
```

**Update**

The problem : 
  I cannot display `Boolean Query` by `IndexSearcher` Object as `search` method of this class (IndexSearcher) should be passed to by a Query! So, it gives me an error when I'm trying to run the following:

```
TopDocs hits = is.search(booleanQuery,10);
...
```

Comment: Exactly what is the problem you have? You are adding to the query just fine. Now just build the query and use it with the IndexSearcher.

Comment: i answered in Update. @user1071777

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `booleanQuery` object is actually an instance of `BooleanQuery.Builder`, not `BooleanQuery`.

After you're done adding all your queries to the builder, you need to call the `build` method.

Ex.

```
TopDocs hits = is.search(booleanQuery.build(),10);
```